# Problems combining (union) Multipolygons in geodjango

Tags: postgis, geodjango, polygon-creation

I'm using geodjango and postgis (1.x),
What is the best way to combine (union) a list of multipolygons.

in what i assume is rather inefficient i'm looping trough like this

```
combined = multipolygon

for item in items:

____combined = combined.union(item.geom)  #geom is a multipolygon
```

Usually this works fine, but often i'm getting the error
 Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSUnion_r".

Here is the geo json version of the item the error is thrown on if it helps

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": 
[ [ [ [ -80.077576, 26.572225 ], 
      [ -80.037729, 26.571180 ], 
      [ -80.080279, 26.273744 ], 
      [ -80.147464, 26.310066 ], 
      [ -80.152851, 26.455851 ], 
      [ -80.138560, 26.538013 ], 
      [ -80.077576, 26.572225 ] 
] ] ] 
}
```

does anyone have anyideas?  the end goal is to take find all the locations (another table) which fall within this  list of n polygons  (using coordinates__within=combined_area)

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Also, the polygons all show up fine in the django admin.

Comment: I found a work around, posted over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524885/problems-combining-union-multipolygons-in-geodjango